# How can i add jsx files in react-boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, redux, boilerplate

I want a authentication flow built upon react-boilerplate framework and all my code in *.jsx files.
I referred the framework to the github source : 
https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

The login jsx component is from :
https://github.com/cornflourblue/react-redux-registration-login-example

I just add LoginPage component in to react-boilderplate , but I just met some challenging problems here:

> Module parse failed: containers\LoginPage\LoginPage.jsx Unexpected token (44:12)
>
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

In the loginpage.jsx, 44 line is in render() function.

```
 return (
        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
...
```

I think the boilerplate doesn't support jsx babel extension, but i couldn't find any help from google.

What the config do i have to change in the react-boilerplate for support jsx?

Comment: Just curious, why did you not use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) as boilerplate? You wont have to configure your project for *.jsx.

Comment: I just want to use i18n feature from boilerplate project.

Comment: You should refer to  react-boilerplate project's  documentation or post this to their [issues](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues)